# How to access class from iOS folder in watchOS App

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, watchkit, watchos

How to access a data class which is in the iOS folder from the watchOS extension folder. If i want to access the class normally by calling my DataService i get this error:

[image]

This file I want to access:

[image]

Comment: At the past I wanted use the same way, but class dose not update it`s Published variables in the way that be usable for watchOS project. or the class does update but watchOS cannot use it. Have you faced the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Select `DataService.swift` file.
- Then click on the top right navigation button to show inspectors.
- Under "Show the file inspector," tick the target name for your watchOS extension.
- This will share that particular file with the watchOS extension.